# JRebel in weblogic environment

Tags: eclipse, weblogic-10.x, jrebel

i created a project in eclipse by enabling jrebel remoting and given deployment URL as

```
http://172.27.162.28:7001/testJrebel/
```

and i deployed the war file in weblogic10 sever before i successfully got output

i did some chnages in my ecllipse IDE by clicking on synchronize

it is giving below error... instead of commiting...

> JRebel Remoting did not respond. The server is up, but is JRebel Remoting enabled?

Answer (score 3):

From [zeroturnaround](http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/jrebel-remoting-server-not-responding/)
http/https ports are used for remoting. If you open the address in your browser, do you get response? Is your server configured to use JRebel remoting? Are you using the latest version 5.1.0 of JRebel in your server?
und.com/forums/topic/jrebel-remoting-server-not-responding/

I think You have to Update **JRebel** from `Help (Menu) >> Check for Updates`

Answer (score 2):

You actually have to enable remoting feature explicitly with **-Drebel.remoting_plugin=true**

Answer (score 0):

When you start WebLogic from command line, you need to specify a JVM parameter `agentpath` in JAVA_OPTIONS. When you set it in startup.sh, it works for the whole Weblogic (both admin server and instance servers).

https://manuals.jrebel.com/jrebel/standalone/launch-from-command-line.html#weblogic-10-x-and-12-x

Afterwards, in your IDE, you need to configure debugging of a *Remote server* and create rebel.xml files for each module, for which you want to enable JRebel.

How to check, that everything works? Start webserver (in logs you should see a JRebel banner) and edit a class. After saving you should see in logs one line, informing that this class has been reloaded.